# How can I redirect to another page once an Electron app has started?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I  have an electron app with multiple html files in the root directory.

- index.html
- page1.html
- page.html

I cannot find a way to redirect from index.html to page1.html once Electro has started.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When your first page is index.html you call that page, when you create your window.

```js
const win = new BrowserWindow(options);
win.loadUrl(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
```

If you want to load another page then maybe

```js
win.loadUrl(`file://${__dirname}/page.html`);
```

could help you.

If the page should be loaded after a user action (e.g. click on a link), you can add the link to your index.html page. Electron works here exactly like a browser.

```html
<a href="page.html">Go to page</a>
```

Comment: I have done it with a link, like in your last example and I have a problem. In the new window I cannot use any package with require('packagename');. It says require is not defined.

Comment: I believe this is a work around. I will suggest JavaScript libraries for routing such as backbone.js or knockout.js

Comment: loading a second url with win.loadUrl(`page2.html`); is causing to the browserwindow to flash a white screen while loading the second page, Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Apparent, both `win.loadFile("page.html")` and ```win.loadUrl(`file://${remote.app.getAppPath()}/page.html`)``` don't work, but yours does work.