# How to redirect to another HTML file with GET variables in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to make an Electron app. In files, in example I have `app.html`, and I need to send GET variable like `?id=54&q=asd` to the `receiver.html`, and then I'll get this `id` and `q` variables on the `receiver.html`.

Everybody knows, in PHP we do it like that:

app.html:

```
<a href="receiver.php?id=54&q=asd">Click Me</a>
```

receiver.php:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id']." ".$_GET['q'];
?>
```

In electron we redirects pages as [this Stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599908/electron-app-multiple-html-files) suggested.

But how can I get the `GET` variables in Electron.js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameters from main process to render processes in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335004/how-to-pass-parameters-from-main-process-to-render-processes-in-electron)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `URLSearchParams` class to parse the URL and get any query variables with the `.get` function, like this:

```
const queryVariables = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
console.log(queryVariables.get('id') + " " + queryVariables.get('q'));
```

I hope this helps.